# Non-numeric value passed to decrement method

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

```
foreach($menuItem1 as &$a){
  $a = $a*$amount;
}

$numArray = array_map('intval', $menuItem1);

foreach($menuItem2 as $in){
    DB::table('ingredients')->where('id', $in)->decrement('ingredient_stock', $numArray);
}
```

Result of $numArray:
array(3) { [0]=> int(6) [1]=> int(8) [2]=> int(24) } array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }

I want to run a query, but get this error: **Non-numeric value passed to decrement method**. Why?

Comment: `$numArray` is array, ok? It's really not a numeric value.

Comment: Ok, do you have a solution?

Comment: try dd($numArray)??

Comment: No more error, but now the query is not executed.  


DB::table('ingredients')->where('id', $in)->decrement('ingredient_stock', dd($numArray));

Comment: why is it "not executed"? error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass value for how much you want to decrement in **decrement** method.

Try the following.

```
$num_i = 0;
foreach($menuItem2 as $in){
    DB::table('ingredients')->where('id', $in)->decrement('ingredient_stock', $numArray[$num_i]);
    $num_i = $num_i + 1;
}
```

Comment: Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

`decrement` expects a numeric value, a single number, and not an array of numbers.

you need to resctructure your `$numArray`. you could make it into an associative array with the menu item id as the key `[ $menuItem1ID => valueForMenuItem1, $menuItem2ID => valueForMenuItem2, ]`

then in your loop instead of `->decrement('ingredient_stock', $numArray);` 
do `->decrement('ingredient_stock', $numArray[$in]);`